# Symfony2 Form Collection not saved into the database (using one-to-many-to-one link entity)

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, many-to-many

I am building an application with an **Article** entity. Every article can have more **Attribute** (and one attribute can have many articles reffering to it).

To manage the connection I am using link entity **AttributeLink**, so the connection is **one-to-many-to-one**. The link entity has additional field to store the attribute **value**.

I have built a **form with collection** that works well. In fact, the solution worked fine and saved all the values correctly. When I went to style the form to look better, the solution stopped working (and that is quite strange to me, because I did no changes to the logic, just tuned up the twig).

Now the **Article is saved** to the database, but **no new row is created in the linked entity** database table.

I went over and over and over my solution, checking it against documentation and all seems to me to be right in the correct place. I am probably missing something small.

Based on the changes I have done and on the behaviour (nothing is saved in the databse table) the only problem I can think of is, that the collection does not pass the data correctly for persistance.

Please advice.

### ArticleController.php

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($article)
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Název'))
            ->add('date', DateType::class, array(
                'label' => false, 
                'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy', 
                'data' => new \DateTime(),
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'html5' => false,
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control_form_input input_half']
                ))
            ->add('quantity_stored', IntegerType::class, array('label' => 'Úvodní množství', 'data' => 0))
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Kategorie', 'choice_label' => 'name', 'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true, 'class' => 'ArticleBundle:Category', 'choices' => $category))
            ->add('state', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Stav', 'choice_label' => 'name', 'class' => 'ArticleBundle:State'))
            ->add('warehouse', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Sklad', 'choice_label' => 'name', 'class' => 'CompanyBundle:Warehouse'))
            ->add('user', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Zodpovědný uživatel', 'choice_label' => 'email', 'class' =>'LoginBundle:User'))
            ->add('attribute', CollectionType::class, array(
                    'entry_type' => AttributeLinkType::class, 
                    'label' => false,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'entry_options' => array('attr' => array('company_id' => $this->session->get('active_company')))
                ))
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array('label' => 'Popis', 'required' => false, 'empty_data'  => ' '))
            ->add('code', HiddenType::class, array('data' => $code))
            ->add('company', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'CompanyBundle:Company', 'choice_label' => 'id', 'choices' => array($company)))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Uložit'))
            ->getForm();
```

### AttributeLinkType.php

```
class AttributeLinkType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->company_id = $options['attr']['company_id'];

        $builder
            ->add('attribute', EntityType::class, 
                    array(
                        'label' => false, 
                        'class' => 'ArticleBundle:Attribute', 
                        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                            return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                            ->join('a.company', 'c')
                            ->where('c.id = '.$this->company_id)
                            ->orderBy('a.name', 'ASC');
                        }
                    )
                )            
            ->add('value', TextType::class, array('label' => false));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => AttributeLink::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

### Article.php

```
     class Article
    {            
        /**
         * Many Article has Many Attribute via link entity
         * 
         * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AttributeLink", mappedBy="article", cascade={"persist"})
         */
        private $attribute;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->attribute = new ArrayCollection();
        }

        public function __toString() {
            return $this->name;
        }

        /**
         * Add attribute
         *
         * @param \AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\AttributeLink $attribute
         * @return Article
         */
        public function addAttribute(\AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\AttributeLink $attribute)
        {   
            $attribute->setArticle($this);

    $this->attribute->add($attribute);

            $this->attribute[] = $attribute;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Remove attribute
         *
         * @param \AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\AttributeLink $attribute
         */
        public function removeAttribute(\AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\AttributeLink $attribute)
        {        
            $this->attribute->removeElement($attribute);
        }

        /**
         * Get attribute
         *
         * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
         */
        public function getAttribute()
        {
            return $this->attribute;
        }
    }
```

### AttributeLink.php

```
class AttributeLink
{
/**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * Attribute value
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $value;

    /**
     * Many Article has Many Attribute via link entity
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Article", inversedBy="attribute")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="article_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $article;

    /**
     * Many Article has Many Attribute via link entity
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Attribute", inversedBy="article")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attribute_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $attribute;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set value
     *
     * @param string $value
     * @return AttributeLink
     */
    public function setValue($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get value
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    /**
     * Set article
     *
     * @param \AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article $article
     * @return AttributeLink
     */
    public function setArticle(\AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article $article = null)
    {        
        $this->article = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get article
     *
     * @return \AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\Article 
     */
    public function getArticle()
    {
        return $this->article;
    }

    /**
     * Set attribute
     *
     * @param \AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\Attribute $attribute
     * @return AttributeLink
     */
    public function setAttribute(\AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\Attribute $attribute = null)
    {                
        $this->attribute = $attribute;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get attribute
     *
     * @return \AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\Attribute 
     */
    public function getAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attribute;
    }
}
```

### Attribute.php

```
class Attribute
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Attribute name
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * Many Attributes have One Company
     * 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AuthenticatedUser\System\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company", inversedBy="article_attribute")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * Many Article has Many Attribute via link entity
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AttributeLink", mappedBy="attribute", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $article;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->article = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Attribute
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set company
     *
     * @param \AuthenticatedUser\System\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company $company
     * @return Attribute
     */
    public function setCompany(\AuthenticatedUser\System\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company $company = null)
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get company
     *
     * @return \AuthenticatedUser\System\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company 
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * Add article
     *
     * @param \AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\AttributeLink $article
     * @return Attribute
     */
    public function addArticle(\AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\AttributeLink $article)
    {                
        $this->article[] = $article;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove article
     *
     * @param \AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\AttributeLink $article
     */
    public function removeArticle(\AuthenticatedUser\ContentManagement\ArticleBundle\Entity\AttributeLink $article)
    {
        $this->article->removeElement($article);
    }

    /**
     * Get article
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getArticle()
    {
        return $this->article;
    }
}
```

### page_content.html.twig collection section

```
<div id="attribute_outer" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-md-12 masonry-container page_list form_attributes_box">
        <div id="attribute_inner" class="card-box_attributes">
            <label class="form_attributes_list_label">Vlastnosti produktu</label>
            <div class="attributes" data-prototype="
                 {% filter escape %}
                    {{ include('ArticleBundle:Article/New:attribute.html.twig', { 'form': form.attribute.vars.prototype}) }}
                 {% endfilter %}   
                 ">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### attribute.html.twig

```
<div class="{{ form.attribute.vars.id }} form_attribute_row">
    {{ form_widget(form.attribute, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control_form_input'} }) }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    {{ form_widget(form.value, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control_form_input'} }) }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

### page_content_scripts.html.twig collections script

```
var $collectionHolder;

        // setup an "add an attribute" link
        var $addTagLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Přidat vlastnost</a>');
        var $newLinkLi = $('<div></div>').append($addTagLink);
        var rmIndex = 0;

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            // Get the ul that holds the collection of tags
            $collectionHolder = $('div.attributes');

            // add a delete link to all of the existing tag form li elements
            $collectionHolder.find('div').each(function() {
                addTagFormDeleteLink($(this));
            });

            // add the "add a tag" anchor and li to the tags ul
            $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

            // count the current form inputs we have (e.g. 2), use that as the new
            // index when inserting a new item (e.g. 2)
            $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

            $addTagLink.on('click', function(e) {
                // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
                e.preventDefault();

                // add a new tag form (see next code block)
                addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);

                $('#attribute_outer').animate({height: '+=46'}, 1);
                $('#attribute_inner').animate({height: '+=46'}, 1);
            });

            // add a new tag form (see next code block)
            addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
        });

        function addTagForm($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
            // Get the data-prototype explained earlier
            var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');

            // get the new index
            var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');

            // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
            // instead be a number based on how many items we have
            var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

            // increase the index with one for the next item
            $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

            // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
            var $newFormLi = $('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12"></div>').append(newForm);
            $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);

            // add a delete link to the new form
            addTagFormDeleteLink($newFormLi);
        }

        function addTagFormDeleteLink($tagFormLi) {
            var $removeFormA = $('<button class="btn btn-danger btn-custom" style="margin-bottom: 4px;"><i class="ion-close-round"></i></button>');

            $($removeFormA).appendTo(".form_attribute_" + rmIndex + "_attribute");
            //$tagFormLi.append($removeFormA);

            rmIndex++;

            $removeFormA.on('click', function(e) {
                // prevent the link from creating a "#" on the URL
                e.preventDefault();

                // remove the li for the tag form
                $tagFormLi.remove();

                $('#attribute_outer').animate({height: '-=46'}, 500);
                $('#attribute_inner').animate({height: '-=46'}, 500);
            });
        }
```

### generated html output

```
<div class="form_attribute_0_attribute form_attribute_row">
    <select id="form_attribute_0_attribute" name="form[attribute][0][attribute]" class="form-control_form_input"><option value="1">Barva</option><option value="2">Hmotnost</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="form_attribute_0_value" name="form[attribute][0][value]" required="required" class="form-control_form_input" type="text">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-custom" style="margin-bottom: 4px;"><i class="ion-close-round"></i></button>
```

### generated prototype

```
data-prototype='<div class="form_attribute___name___attribute form_attribute_row">
    <select id="form_attribute___name___attribute" name="form[attribute][__name__][attribute]" class="form-control_form_input"><option value="1">Barva</option><option value="2">Hmotnost</option></select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="text" id="form_attribute___name___value" name="form[attribute][__name__][value]" required="required" class="form-control_form_input" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

'
EDIT
I enhanced my controller with the following missing lines: 
`$attribute = new AttributeLink();`
`$article->addAttribute($attribute);`

Now there are some additional attribute fields generated by the form and only last entry is saved ... loosing my mind here

Comment: After some time away from keyboard and reviewing the question now via mobile I got suspission that the jquery script part is messed up by two index named variables - one global and one local in a function .... gonna test it out by renaming the global one right when I get back to pc

Comment: I have renamed the global index to rmIndex, but it did not solve the issue

Comment: Can you show the rest of your generated html output? You didn't show the generated prototype.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Not seeing anything obvious, but have to wonder why go through the intermediate entity of AttributeLink? Seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: there are given attributes that can have different values, one article can have multiple attributes of the same type, so I need to store the article-attribute specific value

Comment: I still was not able to solve it, any help appreciated